# Unable to load some websites USB tethering

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-10

I am sharing internet from my Samsung galaxy S10+ to my HP Pavilion 15-n208tx laptop via USB tethering. On my phone, I am getting browsing speeds of upto 10 mbps but while tethering, I am unable to load many websites. I am using the USB type C cable provided with the phone for tethering.

*Example of strange behavior*:

**Sites loading**:

www.google.com

www.instagram.com

**Sites not loading**:

www.codeforces.com

www.amazon.in

Comment: What do you mean not loading? Is the connection  timing out or the site's cannot be reached at all? Is this the  ase with both the phone and the PC or just with PC. Try pinging the sites in both the phone and PC when tethering. Also try tethering in a different PC or maybe in a Linux live boot session just to rule out your current OS is not the problem here.

Comment: The sites are reachable but after quite a long time (minimum 30 sec). It is just the case with the PC on which my OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried pinging the websites on my PC and the ping is just fine. Moreover, I tried USB tethering with a different phone using a type B USB cable on this laptop, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my wired ethernet connection is still active and hence some sites are failing. I disconnected the wired ethernet and my usb tether is working properly for all sites.